# Plt.Scatter at seaborn : Error : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, database, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I'm looking for a solution to solve my problem when i try to plot my figure: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." 
If I remove the data_t_quali['TOR'] for example and just put 'TOR' (as it says on the seaborn website) then I get empty graphics.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data_t_quali1, col='Reussie',col_order=['Reprise en main reussie','Echec de la reprise en main'],hue='Age',hue_order=[20,30,40,50,60 ],size=6,aspect=1.2,palette=sns.light_palette('navy', 4)[1:])

g.map(plt.scatter,data_t_quali1['NombreFixation'],data_t_quali1['TOR'],alpha=0.9, edgecolor='white', linewidth=2, s=300)

fig = g.fig 
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.79, wspace=0.3)
fig.suptitle('Time to take over control (TOR) in fonction of the fixation numbers 2 minutes before the regaining control of the vehicle', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
g.add_legend(title='Age du conducteur')
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)